# Combine text in formula field in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have databasefields to check a condition and return multiline text. For example:

> returnText = ''
>
> ```
>  If TD1 = true then
>       returnText = 'text1'
>  If TD2 = true then
>       returnText = returnText + \n' + 'text2'
>  If TD3 = true then
>       returnText = returnText + \n' + 'text3'
>   return returnText
> ```

How can I do this with a formula field, or what is another way to do this?

Comment: Can't understand your question. It doesn't work or what?

Comment: How to do this? using formulafield? I cannot declare returnText and show text on report?

Comment: Yes, what syntax do you use? I suppose none of supported Basic and Crystal syntaxes support single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using formula. Not sure what syntax you use. It's closer to Basic, but here's a Crystal Syntax version:

```
local stringVar returnText = "";

if TD1 = true then
    returnText := "text1";
if TD2 = true then
    returnText := returnText + chr(13) + "text2";
If TD3 = true then
    returnText := returnText + chr(13) + "text3";
returnText
```

Or with Basic:

```
dim returnText as string
returnText = ""

if TD1 = true then
    returnText = "text1"
end if
if TD2 = true then
    returnText = returnText + chr(13) + "text2"
end if
If TD3 = true then
    returnText = returnText + chr(13) + "text3"
end if
formula = returnText
```